# SQL Query - Count and list 0 instead of Null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have the following SQL table:

[image: Basic structure]

Data base structure & wanted output:

[image: Data base structure & wanted output]

Any idea how the query would look? I would also like to put 0 instead of Null in case there are no results.

br
Stian

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you have only these 4 types of events?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Yes, only these type of events

Comment: You can pivot the data using count and case statements.  To handle the zeros simply use coalesce(column,0) coalesce will replace null with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have fixed `types`, use static `Conditional Aggregate`

```
select cast([Date] as Date),
       count(case when type  = 'Maintenance' then 1 end) as [Maintenance]
       count(case when type  = 'Fault' then 1 end) as [Fault]
       count(case when type  = 'Alarm' then 1 end) as [Alarm]
       count(case when type  = 'Critical Fault' then 1 end) as [Critical Fault]
From yourtable 
Group by cast([Date] as Date)
```

When there is no particular `type` for a `Date` then `Count` aggregate will return `0`

Answer (score 0):

To put 0 instead of Null you need just to do this
ISNULL(Column_Name, 0) for numerics and ISNULL(Column_Name, '0')

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST([Date] AS DATE) Event_date
       sum(Case when type = 'Maintenance' then 1 else 0 end) as Maintenance
      ,sum(Case when type = 'Fault' then 1 else 0 end) as Fault
      ,sum(Case when type = 'Alarm' then 1 else 0 end) as Alarm
      ,sum(Case when type = 'Critical Fault' then 1 else 0 end) as [Critical Fault]
FROM Table
GROUP BY Cast([Date] as Date)
ORDER BY Event_date
```

I'm more of a sum fan here.  No coalesce needed as 1+ or 0 will always be returned as each pivoted column will have a 0 or 1+ value.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @table table (Date datetime NOT NULL, Type varchar(50) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @table
VALUES
  ('08.11.2016 14:23','Maintenance'),
  ('08.11.2016 10:45','Fault'),
  ('08.11.2016 10:44','Alarm'),
  ('08.11.2016 14:23','Critical Falut'),
  ('08.11.2016 14:23','Maintenance'),
  ('08.11.2016 10:45','Fault'),
  ('08.11.2016 10:44','Alarm'),
  ('08.11.2016 14:23','Critical Falut'),
  ('07.11.2016 14:23','Maintenance'),
  ('07.11.2016 10:45','Fault'),
  ('07.11.2016 10:44','Alarm'),
  ('07.11.2016 14:23','Maintenance'),
  ('07.11.2016 10:45','Fault'),
  ('07.11.2016 10:44','Alarm')
;

-- if the value contains a space don't for get to quote it with [] i.e. [Some Value]
SELECT Date = P.DateDay, P.Maintenance, P.Fault, P.Alarm, P.[Critical Falut]
FROM (
  SELECT DateDay = CONVERT(date, Date), Date, Type
  FROM  @table
  ) AS T
PIVOT ( COUNT(Date) FOR Type IN (Maintenance, Fault, Alarm, [Critical Falut]) ) AS P
;
```

edit: I am curious why this was down voted when it is a pivot that exactly answers the users question.